# read record from database with generic lambda

Tags: generics, lambda

```
TEntity temp = null;

foreach (TEntity item in _context.Set<TEntity>())
{
    if (keyPropertyInfo.GetValue(item).ToString() == primaryKey)
    {
        temp = item;
    }
}
```

I write the code in DataAccessBase class, and want to get TEntity by primaryKey, but it's bad efficiency, _context.Set will get all records from table. So I tried:

```
TEntity temp = _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(e => keyPropertyInfo.GetValue(e).ToString() == primaryKey).FirstOrDefault();
```

but it's not working... anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to find an entity by its primary key just use find method:

```
public TEntity Get<TEntity>(string primaryKey) where TEntity : class
    {
        using (var _context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(primaryKey);
        }
    }
```

if you need to find it by other properties you can send the expression to the function like below:

```
public TEntity Get<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class
{
    using (var _context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

and to call it:

```
repo.Get<MyModel>(x=>x.SomeProperty == someValue);
```